# Facebook API "Unsupported get request." on facebook page when using App token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to fetch the images posted by a Facebook page that I own to display on a separate website. Using the graph-api explorer I am able to successfully perform the request using my app and the "Get Access Token" button. When I use the "Get App token" button (so I can make the server-server call in PHP from my app), I get the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

My app settings look like this: 
[image: app settings]

My page settings look like this:

[image: page settings]

Here's the result from the graph explorer after clicking "Get App token":
[image: fb graph api]

Comment: My guess would be that the page is either country or age restricted

Comment: @WizKid If you check my image of page settings, you can see that it's set to visible to everyone.

Comment: Then I would file a bug because the documentation say that any access token is ok.

Comment: I've done that now, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed a bug and has since been resolved:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/386876158135170